# Function. 2 2D arrays, the second is full of 0's, after applying condition,copy the whole row from first 2D array to the second 2D array

Tags: arrays, c

So, for example I have 2 Arrays,  one is

```
0 -1 1 0 1
0 -1 0 0 0
0 1 1 -1 0
0 0 0 -1 0
0 -1 0 1 0
```

the second is full of 0's.
After I meet the condition `a[i][j] == -1 && a[i][k] == 1`, where k=j+1, I need to copy the whole row and put it into the second array, so the result should be:

```
0 -1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 -1 0 1 0
```

I've already alloced the memory for both arrays, and here's the part of the code that I've tried but it doesnt work, it copies the whole array

```
void copy_row(int **a, int **b, int m){
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        b[i]=a[i];
        
    }
}
int main(){
...
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<m ; j++){
        for(int k=j+1; k<m ; k++){
         
        if (a[i][j]==-1 && a[i][k]==1){
            copy_row(a,b,n);
         }
         
      }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please, show how you allocate, those pointer to pointer are very suspicious, usually a 2D array and a pointer to pointer are not compatible (except for pointer to `char`s). `char **` and `char *[]` are interchangeable, but `int **` and `int *[]` are not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a row, you would need to pass the index of the current row to `copy_row`, plus the number of columns.

The call from main could be

```
// Notice that we pass index i and not n
copy_row(m, a, b, i);
```

The copy_row could be:

```
void copy_row(int numOfColumns, int a[][numOfColumns], int b[][numOfColumns], int rowIndex) {
    for (int ii = 0, ii < numOfColumns, ++ii) {
        b[rowIndex][ii] = a[rowIndex][ii];
    }
}
```

You could add a `break` after the call to `copy_row` in the `if` statement. Once a row is copied, there is no need to keep checking the rest of the columns for `-1`.
E.g., you might reduce the checks made by using

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; ++j) {
    if (a[i][j] == -1) {
        for(int k = j + 1; k < m ; ++k) {
            if (a[i][k] == 1) {
                copy_row(m, a, b, i);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thanks for the comment, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that as well.